# I am using "jitsi meet" in Flutter. I want to get rid of the menu tabs on the call screen

Tags: flutter, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I want to hide this part.Please tell me how to do that.
I've added the code for "featureFlags" below the image, and
I wrote the code for "var options = JitsiMeetingOptions(room: url)" below the image.

[image]

My code

```
Future<void> joinMeeting(String url, WidgetRef ref, String docid) async {
  Map<FeatureFlagEnum, bool> featureFlags = {
    FeatureFlagEnum.WELCOME_PAGE_ENABLED: false,
    FeatureFlagEnum.ADD_PEOPLE_ENABLED: false,
    FeatureFlagEnum.CALENDAR_ENABLED: false,
    FeatureFlagEnum.CALL_INTEGRATION_ENABLED: false,
    FeatureFlagEnum.CHAT_ENABLED: false,
    FeatureFlagEnum.INVITE_ENABLED: false,
    FeatureFlagEnum.LIVE_STREAMING_ENABLED: false,
    FeatureFlagEnum.MEETING_NAME_ENABLED: true,
    FeatureFlagEnum.MEETING_PASSWORD_ENABLED: true,
    FeatureFlagEnum.TOOLBOX_ALWAYS_VISIBLE: false,
  };

  var options = JitsiMeetingOptions(room: url)
    ..featureFlags.addAll(featureFlags);
```

Comment: did you get any success yet?

Comment: no,I don't know yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified this flutter plugin for the same issue.
In pubspec.yaml,

```
jitsi_meet:
git:
  url: https://github.com/Techuick/jitsi_meet.git
  ref: jitsimeet_v1
  path: jitsi_meet/
```

For hiding overflow menu button, you can use "overflowMenuEnabled" parameter in JitsiMeetingOptions. Something like this:

```
var options = JitsiMeetingOptions(room: roomText.text)
  ..serverURL = serverUrl
  ..subject = subjectText.text
  ..userDisplayName = nameText.text
  ..userEmail = emailText.text
  ..iosAppBarRGBAColor = iosAppBarRGBAColor.text
  ..audioOnly = isAudioOnly
  ..audioMuted = isAudioMuted
  ..videoMuted = isVideoMuted
  ..overflowMenuEnabled = isOverflowMenuHidden;
```

Comment: how can I define roles for each user in the session??

Like show `OverflowMenu` for **Host**

Comment: Infact, You can define roles in your db and depending on the role you can set overflowmenu boolean when joining session

Comment: am going to make use of it for my current project, but please how often does this repo get updated?

Comment: when i added it to my `pubspec.yaml` file, i got `Cannot resolve directory 'jitsi_meet'` how do i resolve this?

Comment: can you send your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: no need for that, i did flutter clean and build again, everything its working perfectly
thanks for woking on this package,

Comment: how do I remove the `Help` option from the overflowing menu because it's redirecting to jitsi github website